# Better / faster Python code

Tags: python, performance

Yet another noob query here. Quotes like "never write the same code twice" have me trying to ferret out my mistakes; here's one I want to improve:
code in main file:

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    dosomething
```

another way:

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    os_is_nt = True

if os_is_nt:
    dosomething
```

another way, putting this function in an import

```
detectNT()
    if os.name == 'nt':
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

My belief is, without figuring out how to check any speed differences, is that I should cut it back to the original:

```
if os.name == 'nt':
    dosomething
```

but my faith is weak, which is why I'm here.

Also, I'm thinking there's a way to find the local file separator..?
I've written this:

```
def os_file_sep():
    file_separator = "/"
    if os.name == 'nt':
        file_separator = "\\"
    return file_separator
```

Comment: What do you actually need to do with the file separators? The [`os module`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html) probably does what you need already.

Comment: re file separators using the `os.path` module should take care of that for you with its methods like `join`

Comment: There's two separate issues: *don't repeat yourself/one single source of truth* and *performance*. If you write code in a manner that is DRY, where each part of the logic is only expressed once, that may be at odds with performance. Sometimes it's more performant to write it in some unmaintainable way; but then it's unmaintainable, potentially... The question is: **is it too slow?!** If not: write DRY code and don't worry about performance.

Comment: `os.path.sep` and `os.sep ` are path separators

Comment: <slaps forehead> yes os.path.sep, thank you (all).

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan in order to highlight the filename from the path I'm printing one, in say green, then the file separator, then the filename in cyan or such. So `join` was not workable. I see how I can do it now using the `os.path.sep`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## What should you use?

Use `os.path.join` (or `os.path.sep`). Don't reinvent wheel. It's simple and great.

```
>>>os.path.join("foo", "bar")
'foo\\bar'
```

## What if there wasn't this (better) way?

- Value never changes - first way ("direct" `if` check) is IMO best. It's simple and readable (unless you do this check in many different places, then I guess variable could be more error prone).
- Value changes - I would choose variable and `if` check if the check is simple and function if the check is complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Your general question is about performance, so I will answer to that.

The main rule is: **do not worry about low level performance unless you really need it**. That means that you should be careful about algorithms but not about low level optimization at first sight, and always prefer simple and maintainable code.

When you have a performance problem (or suspect you will soon have), profile your code. Python provides useful tools out of the box in the Standard Library. One of them is `profile` or its optimized version `cProfile`. Extract from the manual:

*To profile an application with a main entry point of foo(), you would add the following to your module:*

```
import cProfile
cProfile.run('foo()')
```

*The above action would cause foo() to be run, and a series of informative lines (the profile) to be printed.*

Now you know where your program spend most of its time and you know the parts that deserve low level optimisation.

And here again Python provides out of the box the `timeit` module. *This module provides a simple way to time small bits of Python code. It has both command line as well as callable interfaces. It avoids a number of common traps for measuring execution times*.

For the precise question you asked, the correct answer is David Mašek's one. This one is for the general question of performance. Anyway, if you have doubts about the performances of the different solutions (yours and David's ones), just use `timeit` to be sure, and optionally report here in a self answer.